# Let $H\triangleleft G$. Prove that $G/H$ is abelian iff $ [G, G] \subseteq H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

> The commutator of two elements $a, b \in G$ is defined as
> $[a, b] = aba^{−1}b^{−1}$.

> Let $[G, G] =\langle [a, b] | a, b \in G\rangle $ be the generated subgroup of all commutators of the elements of $G$.

> Let $H\triangleleft G$.   Prove that  $G/H$ is abelian iff $ [G, G] \subseteq H$.

I have previously proved $[G,G] \triangleleft G$ and $G/[G,G]$ is abelian

The following solution is provided, but there are some things I don't understand. I feel need the intermediate steps  they are not provinding to fully understand it. Can someone shed some light?

### Solution:

If $G/H$ is abelian for every $a, b \in G$ it follows that $abH = baH$,that is $aba^{−1}b^{−1} \in H$.

> **(1)  How do they get this?**

so for every  $a, b \in G$ we have $[a, b] = aba^{−1}b^{−1} \in H$,  but now the subgroup

$[G, G]$ generated by the elements of the form $[a, b]$ is contained in $H$.

> **(2) They proved one commutator is in $H$, how does it extent to the whole generated subgroup?**

*Viceversa*, if $ [G, G]  \subseteq H$ then for every $a, b \in G$ we have
$(abH)(a^{−1}b^{−1}H) = H = 1_{G/H}$;

> **(3) I would write $(abH)(a^{−1}b^{−1}H) =[a,b]H$, why does this equals H?**

So $abH = (a^{−1}b^{−1}H)^{−1} = baH$.

Comment: For $(1)$ note that inverse of $ba H$ in $G/H$ is $(ba)^{-1}H=a^{-1}b^{-1}H$ and now multiply both sides of $ab H=baH$ by $(ba)^{-1} H$.

Comment: For $(2)$ note that if a group $G$ generated by $S\subseteq G$, then any element $g\in G$ can be written as $g=s_1^{n_1}\cdots s_k^{n_k}$ for $s_i\in S$ and $n_i\in\Bbb Z$ and $k\in\Bbb N$ is arbitrary.

Comment: For $(3)$ note the group operation $\cdot$ in $G/H$ is defined as, $(xH)\cdot (yH):=(x\cdot y)H$ for any two $x,y\in G$.

Comment: for (2): Is it possible not to put the exponent ?In my notes in a previous part they state  $g$ is of the form $g=s_1.. s_2...s_k$, but why?  anyway then the answer follows because S, in the problem H is a subgroup, so it is closed, right?

Comment: Yes, $s^n:=s\cdot s\cdots s$ ($n$-times) if $n>0$.  $s^n:=s^{-1}\cdot s^{-1}\cdots s^{-1}$  ($-n$-times) for $n<0$. Finally, $s^0:=e$, the trivial element of $G$.

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki Actually no, it lacks the details I needed, which Schaun and Mark have provided. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Dietrich Burde My question is not about the solution as a whole, but about specific details that other post also lacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1)$ It is well known that we have $g_1H=g_2H$ if and only if $g_1^{-1}g_2\in H$. So if $G/H$ is Abelian then for any $a,b\in G$ we have $a^{-1}b^{-1}H=b^{-1}a^{-1}H$ and hence $(b^{-1}a^{-1})^{-1}(a^{-1}b^{-1})=aba^{-1}b^{-1}=[a,b]\in H$. So all the commutators are in $H$.

$(2)$ Since $a,b$ were arbitrary, we actually proved that all the commutators are in $H$. And since $[G,G]$ is by definition the smallest subgroup of $G$ which contains all the commutators this implies $[G,G]\leq H$.

$(3)$ Another standard result about cosets is that we have $gH=H$ if and only if $g\in H$. So since by assumption $[a,b]\in H$ we have $[a,b]H=H$.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Consider $abH=baH$. It is the same as saying

$$\{abh\mid h\in H\}=\{bah'\mid h'\in H\}.$$

So for any $k\in H$, $abk=bak'$ for some $k'\in H$. But then $abkk'^{-1}=ba$, *i.e.*, $a^{-1}b^{-1}ab=k'k^{-1}$, which is equivalent to saying $[a,b]\in H$ since $k'k^{-1}\in H$. (Why?)

(2) Note that $a,b\in G$ are *arbitrary*.

(3) See (1). Since $[a,b]\in [G,G]\subseteq H$, $[a,b]H=H$.

Comment: Not sure what that "why" refers to. If it means why $k'k^{-1}\in H$, because H is closed under its operation

Comment: *Hint:* $$[a^{-1}, b^{-1}]=a^{-1}b^{-1}ab,$$ @J.C.VegaO.

Comment: Sorry: bad timing. I was referring "$[a,b]\in H$", @J.C.VegaO. What you said is correct though.

Comment: I tried to use the inverse of the commutator, but $[a,b]^{-1}=[b,a]$ is not helping

Comment: It's fiddly, I'll grant you that, @J.C.VegaO; I'm trying to recall the trick to it. I'll leave it as an exercise for now. Is that okay?